# Using basinhopping to find the global minimum of a not-so-well hehaved function

Tags: scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have a function of type  R * R-> R defined as

```
f(x,y)=(y-5)^2 if x = 9 
       (x-9)^2 otherwise
```

This function is smooth except near `x = 9`.  It can also be observed that this function is non-negative and

`f(x,y) == 0 <==> (x,y) = (9,5)`.

Thus, (9,5) is the only global minimum of f.  But I find it very hard to locate this point (or approximate it) using `scipy`’s global optimization tool. I have tried with `spicy.optimize.basinhopping`:

```
import scipy.optimize as op

def f(X):
  if X[0]==9:
    return (X[1]-5)**2
  else:
    return (X[0]-9)**2


res=op.basinhopping(f,[7.0,7.0],minimizer_kwargs={'method':'powell'},niter=100,stepsize=50)
print res
```

And I get

```
    fun: 3.1554436208840472e-30
    nfev: 5806
 message: ['requested number of basinhopping iterations completed successfully']
     nit: 100
       x: array([  9.        ,  20.01509711])
```

Is there a way to set properly basinhopping so the true global minimum (9,5) can be found?

Comment: Maybe this http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/glopt/software_l.html#nonsm and this link http://plato.asu.edu/sub/multiobj.html

Comment: Do you know the discontinuity in beforehand

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely hard problem for any numerical optimization algorithm.  The minimizer will move towards `x=9`, but the convergence criterion will be reached long before 9 is actually reached.  It would have to get to *exactly* 9 before it knows anything about the y axis.  That can only happen through luck or pre-existing knowledge about the problem.  Even a brute force optimization technique like a grid search could only solve it through luck.

`l-bfgs-b` stops after 2 iterations thinking it found the solution at [9.00000017,  7.] with the function value 2.773339593234183e-14 and the gradient [  3.43066965e-07,   0.00000000e+00]